# Mongoose error - no 'toObject' method after upgrade

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose model in which I call the `toObject` method in a hook:

```
Product.post('init', function() {
   // if (typeof this.toObject === 'function') - works but why do I need it?
    this._original = this.toObject();
});
```

This has worked fine in the pastbut after a Mongoose upgrade this error is thrown:

```
TypeError: Object #<EventEmitter> has no method 'toObject'
at EventEmitter.Product.pre.self (/opt/run/snapshot/package/models/product.js:426:25)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at model.Document.(anonymous function) [as emit] (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:88:42)
at model.Document.init (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:271:8)
at completeMany (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1075:12)
at Object.cb (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1030:11)
at Object._onImmediate (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mquery/lib/utils.js:137:16)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:345:15)
```

I should note that this occurs when launching the app. I can do a check to prevent error but the issue is that I need the toObject function and would like to understand how this error can be thrown.

I am not finding docs on any changes. Any ideas?

**Edit** I realized my issue was caused by a loose `package.json` spec for Mongoose which caused my host (nodejitsu) to use what I think is a `4.x` version instead of my local `3.8.x` branch. If I lock down the version exactly the problem does not occur.

Comment: Can you show us how you define the Post schema, including any defined instance and static methods for its model?

Comment: Given your `typeof` check, I don't see any way for that code to throw that error. Are you sure that's the code that's throwing the exception?

Comment: @JohnnyHK - so sorry - that is a check that I added to prevent error - edited post. If I do the typeof check then no error but then functionality I need doesn't work.

Comment: Ok it has to do with Jitsu using Mongoose 4+. A user posted the answer but then took it off. Mongoose 4 hooks are different. Locking the version did the trick - I had the old style ^.

Comment: I removed my answer because I realized that the `_original` value was not persisting to the later hooks. I appended my code to an open issue regarding this on Github. https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2363

Comment: @BrianShamblen nevertheless, my issue was caused by a 4.x upgrade. Since you led me in the correct direction you can add some semblance of an answer regarding that and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @Yashua I updated my old answer and undeleted it. I'll let you know if I get a response about the bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere between the late version 3.8.x and 4.0 the post `init` hook was changed, but not documented. Prior to the change `this` referenced the current document, but now `this` is the event emitter that triggered the hook call. The new way to access the current doc is by adding a parameter to the hook function, just like the pre `save` and `remove` hooks.

```
schema.post('init', function(doc) {
    doc._original = doc.toObject();
});
```

Unfortunately, since this change, any non-schema properties that are added to the document appear to be lost between the post `init` and pre `save` hooks, so there's no way to fix this right now.

I opened an issue ([#2952](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2952)) on Github last Friday. There are currently 387 open issues, so I'm not sure how quickly this will get resolved. I'll post an update if I hear anything.

Comment: Good to know - however I am on 3.8.