# Mongoosejs - Can I modify docs in post query middleware of 'find'?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using mongoose.js version 5.1.6. Is there a way to execute doc.toObject() automatically after query `find`? I'm not sure if I can do it in middleware of `find`.

```
schema.post('find', function(docs) {
  // Can I change the docs that return by find() by modify the docs here?
})
```

Comment: *"Can I change the docs that return by find() by modify the docs here?"* - Have you... tried?

Comment: You can chain `.lean()` to your query. `toObject()` works on documents, `.lean()` works on the query. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean Of course, you can't use any mongoose model stuff on those objects...

Comment: @ippi Yes, but I use `toObject()` because it can transform the original data like remove some sensitive info

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29988752/1497533  .post('init' seems to do the trick

Comment: Seems like it would be better to use .select to tell the db server to not return that sensitive info at all -- but you can use a post init or a post find

Answer (score 5):

yes you can. You have to do something like this

```
schema.post('find', function(docs) {
  // Here you can modify the doc returned by find
doc._doc.<some attribute> = 'asdasdasd'
})
```